# How can I remove blur / blur and rotate at the same time?

Tags: python, rotation, blur

I am a beginner in python and learning about PIL and tkinter.

Now what I am trying is to edit a image and  I am struggling from blur and rotate.

When I blur an image, I cannot get rid of it without rotating it. (I want to make a button to on/off blur)

And if I blur/rotate an image,
Another one doesn't work at the same time.

How can I solve this problem? here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

img=None
tk_img=None
angle=0

def open():
    global img, tk_img
    filename=fd.askopenfilename()
    img=Image.open(filename)
    tk_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.create_image(250,250,image=tk_img)
    window.update()

def quit():
    window.destroy()

def image_rotate():
    global img,tk_img,angle
    angle=angle+45
    tk_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.rotate(angle))
    canvas.create_image(250,250,image=tk_img)
    window.update()

def image_blur():
    global img,tk_img
    tk_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR))
    canvas.create_image(250,250,image=tk_img)
    window.update()
    

window = tk.Tk() #윈도우 생성
canvas=tk.Canvas(window,width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

menubar = tk.Menu(window) #메뉴바 생성

filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar) #파일메뉴를 메뉴바에 달아줌 
filemenu.add_command(label="picture", command=open)
filemenu.add_command(label="exit", command=quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="파일", menu=filemenu)

imagemenu=tk.Menu(menubar)
imagemenu.add_command(label="rotate",command=image_rotate)
imagemenu.add_command(label="blur",command=image_blur)
menubar.add_cascade(label="movement", menu=imagemenu)

window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: We do not understand what you mean, please provide some code or screenshot to support your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite obvious, your `img` object as seen is only defined/updated in `open()`, so the image will always refer to the original image selected and not the new edited image, so to show the change store it in a new variable and then globalize it.

Also note that you are creating a new canvas image every time you call the function, which is not efficient, so make a single canvas image and then update it each time, inside the function using `itemconfig()` method.

```
def open():
    global img, tk_img

    filename = fd.askopenfilename()
    img = Image.open(filename)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.itemconfig('img',image=tk_img) # Update image

def image_rotate():
    global tk_img, angle, img

    angle += 45 # More pythonic to always use += rather than a = a + 10
    img = img.rotate(angle)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.itemconfig('img',image=tk_img) # Update image
    angle -= 45

def image_blur():
    global tk_img, img

    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.itemconfig('img',image=tk_img) # Update image
    

canvas = tk.Canvas(window,width=500,height=500)
canvas.create_image(250,250,tag='img') # Create initial canvas object
canvas.pack()
```

Also take a look at how I formatted your code to make it look more near, follow [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, and I could sucsessfully rotate/blur at the same time. But I found a problem while applying your code; rotate doesn't work well. It moves like +45, +90, +135, +180... (not +45, +45,+45...) maybe it also remember the angel changes

Comment: Ah, I fixed it adding angle=angle-45 at the end. Thank you so much!

Comment: @강감찬 Keep in mind, you can also say `angle -= 45` is same as `angle=angle-45`.

Answer (score 0):

You can blur the image using opencv package

```
import cv2 
  

img = cv2.imread('imagepath') 
  
blurImg = cv2.blur(img,(10,10)) 
cv2.imshow('blurred image',blurImg)
  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or u can check the documentation of opencv to blurr the image.
U can also rotate image using opencv

```
# importing cv2
import cv2

src = cv2.imread(path)
window_name = 'Image'
image = cv2.rotate(src, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
  # Displaying the image
cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Why `opencv`, `PIL` can do it

Comment: The opencv or computer vision library is fast and provide great flexibilty  then PIL

Comment: If u want to continue with PIL then check out this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_blur_an_image.htm

Comment: What I meant was, why import/install another library when PIL has everything you need with `tkinter` as well as image.

Comment: yaa , there is some good somethings about PIL

Comment: But u can also used the combination of opencv and tkinter

Comment: Can you? Does opencv has any function that will return a `PhotoImage` object to be recognized with tkinter?

Comment: your output image will be provided by Opencv . But If u want to display your output image on tkinter window and to get recognized by tkinter   then u will need pil.